# Let $A$ be the set of all sub sequential limits of the sequence $\lbrace a_n \rbrace $. Then $A$ is closed. Why?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $A$ be the set of all sub sequential limits of the sequence $\lbrace a_n \rbrace $. Then $A$ is closed.

But why? I understand that when there are a finite number of elements in $A$ then clearly it is closed.

But what if we have an infinite number of elements?

Thanks for the help

Comment: In what context are we? In what kind of space are we arguing? A metric space?

Comment: Yes metric spaces only

Answer (score 1):

If were are in a metric (or any other first countable) space $X$, it suffices to show that $A$ is sequentially closed. I doubt, that $A$ is closed in general. So let $(\alpha_n)$ a sequence in $A$ converging to some $x \in X$. Let $(U_k)$ a countable decreasing neighbourhood base at $x$ (in the metric case we consider $1/n$-balls), then given $k \ge 1$ and already chosen $n_1, \ldots, n_{k-1}$, there is some $N$ such that $\alpha_n \in U_k$ for $n \ge N$,  as $\alpha_n \to x$. As $\alpha_n$ is the limit of some subsequence of $(a_n)$, there is an $n_k > n_{k-1}$ such that $a_{n_k} \in U_k$. Then $(a_{n_k})$ is a subsequence of $(a_n)$, as the $U_k$ are decreasing, we have $a_{n_k} \in U_l$ for $k \ge l$, hence, as the $U_k$ are a base at $x$, we have $a_{n_k} \to x$, that is $x \in A$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that if you have a countable set in some topological space, you can arrange it into a sequence such that limits of its subsequences are exactly limits of sequences in the original set. So in any countable sequential space which is not Fréchet—Urysohn there is a sequence such that limits of its subsequences form a set which is neither closed not sequentially closed.